# Menu items dont drop down (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, menu

I have actually the problem that the sub menu items are not dropped down by clicking on the menu.
Please can you tell me what I'm doing wrong and help me to fix this problem?

Here is the xaml-code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="MenuItem" x:Key="myStyle">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFEAA40D"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="150"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="50"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="15"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                    <Border x:Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="2">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" ContentSource="Header"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FFEAA40D"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFC3670B"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFEAA40D"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<DockPanel>
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="File" Style="{StaticResource myStyle}">
            <MenuItem Header="Close" />
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Tools" Style="{StaticResource myStyle}">
            <MenuItem Header="Create"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Edit"></MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Help" Style="{StaticResource myStyle}">
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <Grid/>
</DockPanel>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `ControlTemplate` you have not added `Popup`, that's why your sub menu item is not getting displayed. I have changed to your *XAML*; refer below.

```
<Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Grid>
            <Border x:Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="2">
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" ContentSource="Header"/>
            </Border>
            <Popup IsOpen="{Binding Path=IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Placement="Bottom" x:Name="SubMenuPopup" 
                   Focusable="false" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}">
                <Border x:Name="SubMenuBorder" BorderBrush="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Menu}}}" 
                        BorderThickness="1" Padding="2,2,2,2">
                    <Grid x:Name="SubMenu" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">                       
                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" Background="#FFEAA40D" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </Popup>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FFEAA40D"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>         
    </ControlTemplate>
</Setter.Value>
```

Comment: Thank you. It works with your solution !

Comment: @user10223487 Gald I was able to help you !!